# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

Я парсю этот [ресурс](http://vesti.kz).Беру заголовок,дату и контент новости.

Выходит следующие сообщение об ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 130, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 112, in call_all_func
    item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 35, in get_item_title
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 267, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Как я понял из ошибки,ошибка содержится в этом участке кода:

> ```
> # < Собираем заголовки с страницы.
> def get_item_title(item_page,title_rule):
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
>     item_title = soup.find(title_rule[0],{title_rule[1]:title_rule[2]})
>     print(item_title)
>     return item_title['content']
> ```
>
> В `title rule[0]=meta` , `title_rule[1]=property` , `title_rule[2]=og:title`

Я решил сделать `print(item_title)`
На выводе:

```
vesti
кол-во ссылок: 34
http://vesti.kz//khl/269571/
<meta content='Прямая трансляция первого матча "Барыса" в новом сезоне КХЛ' property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//profi/269572/
<meta content='"Я вернусь в Украину чемпионом мира". Деревянченко сделал очередное заявление перед боем с Головкиным' property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//mirfutbol/269569/
<meta content="Криштиану Роналду составил завещание" property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//wta/269568/
<meta content="Путинцева показала лучший результат в карьере и завершила выступление на US Open " property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//mirfutbol/269566/
<meta content="Месси получил приз фонда Папы Римского " property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//amateur/269565/
<meta content="Казахстанский боксер рассказал о подготовке к ЧМ и включил Узбекистан в число главных соперников" property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//national/269564/
<meta content="Сборная Казахстана начала подготовку к матчам с Кипром и Россией в отборе на Евро-2020" property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//sportsout/269563/
<meta content="Китайский миллиардер из рейтинга Forbes передал Головкину эстафету в челлендже" property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//uefa/269509/
<meta content='Кто из звезд "Манчестер Юнайтед" может приехать в Казахстан на матч с "Астаной" в Лиге Европы' property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//france/269562/
<meta content="ПСЖ подписал трехкратного победителя Лиги чемпионов и отдал в аренду чемпиона мира" property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//amateur/269561/
<meta content="Василий Левит оценил свою форму и озвучил задачу на ЧМ-2019 по боксу " property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//mirfutbol/269560/
<meta content="ФИФА назвала трех претендентов на награду лучшему футболисту года" property="og:title"/>
http://vesti.kz//profi/269547/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 130, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 112, in call_all_func
    item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 35, in get_item_title
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 267, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

После вывода (если я правильно понял) код ругается на эту [ссылку](http://vesti.kz/profi/269547/).

Как решить эту ошибку? По ошибке мне понятно только

> что объект типа 'NoneType' не имеет len ()

Comment: Убедительная просьба компоновать свои схожие вопросы в один.

Comment: @strawdog,я думаю эти вопрос разные.И они не так сильно похожи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел исходники **BeautifulSoup** и согласно им у него такой конструктор:

```
def __init__(self, markup="", features=None, builder=None,
                 parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, exclude_encodings=None,
                 **kwargs):
    ...

    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
    ...
```

А с учетом вашего кода:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
```

и той ошибки, это обозначает, что `item_page` равен `None`. Нужно добавить проверку, типа:

```
if item_page is None:
    return

soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
...
```

Comment: Благодарю ! Ваш ответ мне помог !